# Why is appendChild not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to create three elements (parent, and one child) but the third element which is an `<a>` tag is not appending to `modalChild` event thought it’s creating it correctly.

```js
modal = document.createElement("div");
    modal.className = "parent";
 modalChild = document.createElement("div");
 modalChild.className = "child";
    btnClose = document.createElement("a");
 btnClose.className = "btnClose";
 btnClose.textContent = "X";

 modal.appendChild(modalChild);
 modalChild.appendChild(btnClose);

 document.body.appendChild(modal);
 modal.style.display = "flex";
```

`modalChild` is being appended to modal correctly but `btnClose` is not appending to `modalChild`. Does anyone see the problem with the code?

Comment: @XYZ OHh now I can see it appending but its dissapearing very quickly.. after like 0.2s

Comment: @Xufox no, there are no errors :(

Comment: OHH i think i know why its dissapearing its because im inserting new html with the responseText from an ajax call and its replacing everything inside the modal child

Comment: @Madtin check my answer.It is not disappearing

Comment: @XYZ yeahh man you answer was correct but I think ill need to create another child for the button to not dissapear :D thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @XYZ don't know how to do that :/

Comment: please upvote /accept the aswer.You will have the option to mark  after sometime.a green checkimage will show https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147533/342803

Comment: @XYZ done :) ewew

Comment: Sorry.My mistake Your code has no issues.it would work even if you append `btnClose` after appending `modalChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works porperly.You can append to `modalChild`  in any order

```js
modal = document.createElement("div");
modal.className = "parent";
modalChild = document.createElement("div");
modalChild.className = "child";
btnClose = document.createElement("a");
btnClose.className = "btnClose";
btnClose.textContent = "X";

modalChild.appendChild(btnClose);
modal.appendChild(modalChild);

document.body.appendChild(modal);
modal.style.display = "flex";
```